# How to clone a vmware workstation Ubuntu to another laptop?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, backup, vmware, clone

I have a windows 7 laptop, which has vmware workstation installed on it. An Ubuntu OS (and many programs) are installed inside vmware.

Now I have another windows 7 laptop, and I want to clone the vmware image from previous laptop to this one, without having to install Ubuntu and its software again.

How can I do this !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found the answer in this link:

https://kb.vmware.com/kb/2030609

---

***Summary:***

To copy the virtual machine:

1. Shut down your virtual machine. ...
2. Select the folder where the virtual machine is stored and press Ctrl+c.
3. Select the location where you want to copy the virtual machine.
4. Press Ctrl+v. ...
5. Power on the copied virtual machine.